# Webview JavascriptInterface loadUrl Wrong Thread

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a problem with the webview and the javascriptinterface. The webview is inside a fragment, which can removed from the viewpager. Sometimes i call the method loadUrl and i am on the wrong thread and the app crash. That crash is ok if iam on a background thread and i call loadUrl from the background thread without a post to the UI-Thread. But i have implemented the following and with this i think the crash shouldnt happen:

```
mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + _callback + "()");
            }
        });
```

Nevertheless i get sometimes the following crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'JavaBridge'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {189b08de} called on Looper (JavaBridge, tid 160593) {2c1874b2}, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {189b08de})
```

I cant found out when this happens and this is not reproducable.
Can this happen when the fragment is removed from the viewpager and i call the loadUrl method?

Anyone a idea when this happens?

Comment: Do you attempt to call any WebView methods from methods marked with @JavascriptInterface?

Comment: Usually i call all WebView methods from the "javascriptInterface" methods. But sometimes i am in the background thread e.g NFC Scan and then i have to call the post method from the webview. Thats why i call the post method generally.

Comment: The error indicates that you are attempting to call a WebView method directly from an injected method. These methods are executed on a special background thread (see `addJavascriptInterface` docs), called `JavaBridge`. You should also use `post` when you access WebView from it, similar to what you do from your other background methods.

Comment: Ok thank you. My answer wasnt clear enough. I have a base method which is called, if i want to inject javascript. In my app there is no javascipt injection without the post method. Hmmm

Comment: Yeah, that's puzzling then. There should be a stack trace somewhere in logcat for these threading violations -- maybe it will help. This is the code that performs the check: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebView.java#L2282

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that i cant reproduce the issue. But i have the stacktrace from a user. This trace is cutted, because i use the post method and i cant see any info. :(